# Generic protocol property declaration

Tags: swift

Suppose I have a protocol with an associated type T

```
protocol Helper{
    associatedtype T
    func help(_ item: T)
}
```

in a class, I want to declare a property

```
class Manager<T>{
    let item: T?
    let helper: Helper<T>
//Error: Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Helper'

    let anotherHelper: Helper 
//Error: Protocol 'Helper' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
}
```

How do I declare and use the helper property in such way that it enforces the type of the class conforming to the Helper protocol?

I'm sure a lot of people with a background in Java/C# or other similar languages get stuck while attempting to do similar things

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you could make `T` in `Manager<T>` to be a `Helper` instead:

```
class Manager<T> where T : Helper {
    let item: T.T?
    let helper: T

    init(helper: T) {
        self.helper = helper
        item = nil
    }
}
```

And if you want a `Helper<Int>`, you do:

```
class IntHelper : Helper {
    typealias T = Int

     // ... 
}
```

And then use `Manager<IntHelper>`.

Comment: Even though this does seem to solve this particular case, it does not answer the question. Normally T would be a model, and the helpers are consumers that perform action on/with the model. How would the code that does exactly this look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might need a type eraser:

```swift
struct AnyHelper<T>: Helper {
    private let helpFunc: (T) -> Void

    init<H>(_ helper: H) where Helper.T == T {
        helpFunc = helper.help
    }

    func help(_ item: T)
        helpFunc(item)
    }
}
```

and then use the type eraser in your class:

```swift
class Manager<T>{
    let item: T?
    let helper: AnyHelper<T>

    init<H>(item: T, helper: H) where H.T == T {
        self.item = item
        self.helper = AnyHelper(helper)
    }
}
```